# Django multi-form validation from different models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have been struggling to normalize a few tables/models I have in Django that are to be used in one large form.

Let's say I have 2 forms based off of 2 models, 1 of which is dependant of the other. Is there a way to add form validations in 1 model when a specific selection is made in a different model?

The cleaned_data from 1 form isn't available in the other form, is the primary issue. I have instantiated both forms in the same view though.

So basically, in 1 form I need to reference fields which are in a different model (a different modelForm that's instantiated on the same page)

## Form2 based off table/model2 :

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    if 'model1_field' in cleaned_data and not cleaned_data['model2_field']:
      self.add_error('model2_field', forms.ValidationError('This field is required.'))
    else:
       print('No validations are needed')
```

More details on the dependency (trying to follow concepts of db normalization), and there are a bunch of fields that are required in model2, only when 'selection2'or 'is_option1' from  model1 is selected.

```
--- Models------
MULTI_OPTIONS = (
    ('selection1', 'selection1'), 
    ('selection2', 'selection2') # Display and make model2 required
)

class Model1(models.Model):
    primary_key = models.CharField(db_column='primary_table1_key', max_length=10) # Maps tocommon key for all related tables

    is_selected = models.BooleanField(db_column='IsSelected', blank=True, default=None)

    multi_select_options = MultiSelectField(db_column='SelectedOptions', max_length=150, choices = MULTI_OPTIONS, blank=True, null=True)  
    is_option1 = models.BooleanField(db_column='IsOption1', blank=True, null=True, default=None) # No validations needed for Model1SubOptions
    is_option2  = models.BooleanField(db_column='IsOption2', blank=True, null=True, default=None)# If option2 or 'selection2' is made in Model1, then make required sub_selections and all other fields in Model1SubOptions

    class Meta:
        managed = True


# This should become required if Model1 specific option (from a multiselect (Or) a specific boolean field is set to true)
class Model2(models.Model):
    primary_key = models.CharField(db_column='primary_table1_key', max_length=10) # Maps tocommon key for all related tables
    sub_selections = MultiSelectField(db_column='SubOptions', max_length=150, choices = (('Some', 'Some'), ('Other','Other')), blank=True, null=True)
   other_field2 = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='OtherField2', blank=True, null=True)

---------- Forms ---------
class Model1Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Model1
        fields = (  'is_selected', 'multi_select_options', 'is_option1', 'is_option2')

        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super().clean()
             if('multi_select_options' in cleaned_data):
                multi_select_options = cleaned_data['multi_select_options']
                if(not multi_select_options): 
                     self.add_error('multi_select_options', forms.ValidationError('This field is required')) 
            #  if(('selection1' in multi_select_options) and check_data_does_not_exist(cleaned_data, 'model2')):
                # Validate model2


class Model2Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Model2
        fields = (  'sub_selections', 'other_field2')

        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super().clean()
            #  if(('selection1' in multi_select_options) and check_data_does_not_exist(cleaned_data, 'multi_select_options')):
                # Validate model2
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from creating one form for creating both?

Comment: Can you share an example of the dependency that the models have on each other?

Comment: updated my question with more details

Comment: @IainShelvington how can I do that? can we create 1 form from multiple models? That would solve this issue I think?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a form that has all the fields from both models, you can then do all validation in one clean method and then your view can handle saving he individual models

```
class CombinedForm(forms.Form):

    # All fields from Model1
    # All fields from Model2

    def clean(self):
        # Do all validation for fields that are dependent on each other


class CombinedView(FormView):

    form_class = CombinedForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Model1.objects.create(
            param1=form.cleaned_data['param1'],
            param2=form.cleaned_data['param2'],
        )
        Model2.objects.create(
            param3=form.cleaned_data['param3'],
            param4=form.cleaned_data['param4'],
        )
```

Comment: will this work for an edit? I'm assuming a .save() in a view would still work? I'm not sure how to add the commented section in your code sample - #All fields from Model1, Model2 in the same form

Comment: Since this is not a `ModelForm` it does not have a `save()` function unfortunately. Without knowing exactly what your models represent, I would say that maybe all your fields should just be in one model and conditionally required

Comment: would this work https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html#working-with-modelforms

Comment: I do need some sort of table normalization - the model2 is valid only if there's a specific field selection in model1.  So, technically it doesn't need to be within model1 itself. I want to make the form work in Django but also don't want to compromise the database model. I could add a foreign key in Model2 that connects to Model1, if that helps in any way?

Comment: While this is not the route I went, I am chosing this as the answer as the explanation helped me to get what I wanted. I created a model (similar to a db view) - that has all the fields from both models, and validate on the view - instead of the 2 individual models. So, the form does use both the models technically, but from the custom model.